# Не загружается файл в php

Tags: php, html

Всем привет. 
Помогите с проблемой. Есть форма https://pastebin.com/s5UkFjC2
В ней отправка файла, файл загружается, отправляется http://prntscr.com/g3df1x но до скрипта не доходит, в var_dump его нету. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А как вы в var_dump хотели бы его видеть? Я так понимаю, если файл, то название? Сохраните его в начале на сервере.

Comment: @erm у меня $_POST['img] = null

Comment: Оно идет не в POST, а в FILES

Comment: @erm Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы загружаете файл с `type="file"`, то ваш файл будет здесь `$_FILES['img']`